# How can I use pester v5 configuration or container with four standard arguments?

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm trying to invoke a pester script, moving from pester V4.6.0 to V5.3.1

The V4 arguments I used to use, when invoking pester were:

```
-supplying custom parameters
-OutputFormat NUnitXML
-OutputFile $xmlpath
-EnableExit
```

However, it seems for v5, I need to invoke Pester using either a configuration OR a container, neither of which cater fully for the arguments I used in V4. The limitations seem to be:

**Invoke-Pester -Configuration $pesterConfig**
where $pesterConfig doesn't like me specifying custom data params in it, eg:
Data = @{dataFactoryName = $dataFactoryName;}

or

**Invoke-Pester -Container $container -ErrorAction Stop -Output Detailed -CI**
where $container doesn't like me specifying:
-OutputFormat NUnitXML
-OutputFile $xmlpath
-EnableExit

How can I more efficiently use either container or configuration, to allow me to specify the following 4 things:

```
-supplying custom parameters
-OutputFormat NUnitXML
-OutputFile $xmlpath
-EnableExit
```

One work around, would be to settle for using configuration, which caters for 3 of my 4 arguments, and pass custom data to a file or env variable and read it in within the invoked ps script. Probably not ideal though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to use configuration and container together:

```
        $container = New-PesterContainer -Path "..." -Data @{
            customParamA= "value"; 
            customParamB= "value"; 
        }

        $pesterConfig = [PesterConfiguration]@{
            Run = @{
                Exit = $true
                Container = $container
            }
            Output = @{
                Verbosity = 'Detailed'
            }
            TestResult = @{
                Enabled      = $true
                OutputFormat = "NUnitXml"
                OutputPath   = $xmlpath
            }
            Should = @{
                ErrorAction = 'Stop'
            }
        }

        Invoke-Pester -Configuration $pesterConfig
```